# UDP Broadcast Messages to all nodes in OMNET++ INET

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am using OMNET++ INET for Ad hoc networks. I would like to send the UDP packet to multiple end nodes so that they all receive the same packet and not that the end node is chosen randomly. How should I set the destAddress in file omnetpp.ini?

Answer (score 1):

Send it to 255.255.255.255 which is the IP broadcast address. Or you can send to the local broadcast address which looks something like 10.0.0.255 (if you have an 8 bit subnet). The lower layers will know how to deal with these addresses and do the appropriate broadcast on the local network.

Comment: how do I know the number of bits for the subnet? i'm using the Ipv4NetworkConfigurator and  by default there is    xml config = default(xml("<config><interface hosts='**' address='10.x.x.x' netmask='255.x.x.x'/></config>")). so I should use 255.255.255.255 or 10.255.255.255?

Comment: but this does not solve the problem yet. I thought about taking the UdpBasicApp.cc and the UdpBasicApp.h and renaming and modifying them but I do something wrong when I put them in my project as I get an error: "fatal error: inet/applications/base/ApplicationPacket_m.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Conny did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send to **specific** nodes (not to all nodes) then you should either use multicast addresses (but that's pretty complicated to set up), or you indeed need to modify the UDPBasicApp and change the behavior that it can send out also packets to multiple addresses. i.e. instead of the random selecion from the host list, you could implement a loop sending out to all addresses. Or you could keep the random selection behavior and use a different syntax to denote nodes that should be treated as a single group for sending. For example `"host1,host2,host3 host4,host5"` would mean: choose randomly from either `host1,host2,host3` or `host4,host5` and then send out the UDP packet to all hosts in the comma separated group.

One last tip: If you don't insist to use UDP, PingApp does support sending out pings to multiple hosts in the target address. It can in fact ping all host interfaces in the simulation with the `*` notation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for you, but I used the `UdpBasicBurst` node application and set the `destAddresses` field to 'Broadcast'.

Answer (score 0):

Even after using UdpBasicBurst node application and setting the destAddresses field to 'Broadcast' I am not getting it.Could anyone have any another suggestions please

Comment: Please do not use answers to comment.